# Is Inverse image of an small submodule under an epimorphism small?

Tags: ring-theory, modules

**Definition** A submodule $N$ of a module $M$ is said to be  small if there is no proper submodule $K$ of $M$ such that $N+K=M$. If $N$ is an small submodule of a module $M$, we write $N\leq_s M$.

**Question:** If $f:M\rightarrow M$ is an epimorphism such that $ker(f)\leq_s M$, then $N\leq_s M\implies f^{-1}(N)\leq_s M$.

Proof: Since $N\leq_s M$, there exists a proper submodule $K$ such that $N+K=M$. Then $f^{-1}(N)+f^{-1}(K)=f^{-1}(N+K)=f^{-1}(M)=f^{-1}(f(M))=M+ker(f)=M$. Also $f^{-1}(K)\neq M$ as $f^{-1}(K)=M$ implies that  $M=f(M)=f(f^{-1}(K))=K\cap Im(f)=K\cap M=K$ which is a contradiction of the fact that $K$ is proper. Thus, $f^{-1}(N)\leq_s M$.

Comment: The $N \leq_s M$ means that you *cannot* find a proper submodule $K$ of $M$ such that $N+K=M$. What does the first sentence of your proof says?

Comment: Thank you so much. Now, I have understood.